# Disable autofocus on TextField in SwiftUI after App launch

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, appkit

macOS 12 sets the TextField as first responder on launch for a few seconds before this changes.

Tried calling the methods below onAppear, didFinishLaunching, willFinishLaunching, init() of the main app

```
       NSApp.keyWindow?.makeFirstResponder(nil)
       NSApp.keyWindow?.resignFirstResponder()
```

There is a brief delay of a few seconds before the app automatically removes focus.

How to prevent this behaviour ? I have some animations which are triggered when the TextField is focused.

I'm using

```
 enum Focus { case some, none }

 @FocusState var focus : Focus
```

I've observed that on launch focus is set to some and then to nil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This really looks like a bug (file a feedback to Apple if you want).

A found workaround is to disable temporary control on launch (disabled `TextField` cannot get focus) and reenable it in next event cycle.

Tested with Xcode 13.3 / macOS 12.2

Here is main part:

```
TextField("", text: $txt)
    .disabled(disabled)     // << here !!
    .onAppear { 
       DispatchQueue.main.async { disabled = false } // << here !!
    }
```

[Complete code in project is here](https://github.com/Asperi-Demo/4SwiftUI/blob/master/PlayOn_macOS/PlayOn_macOS/Findings/TestTextFiledFocusOnLaunch.swift)

Comment: Very annoying bug, if you have multiple fields, it jumps to the next...
Fixed it with a Stack around it.